# Autohotkey script to do some functions on other window while holding a button

Tags: autohotkey

I want to write a script for my dictionary application, so that when I hold the key <kbd>j</kbd> for a short time then it active the existed KMPlayer window and send space and maximize it( by sending middle button of the mouse) and if KMPlayer doesn't exist it sends <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Here is my script :

```
#IfWinActive Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary
~$j::
KeyWait,j,T0.2
 If (ErrorLevel) 
 {
  If WinExist ("KMPlayer 64X")
  {
   WinActivate
   sleep,50
   SendInput,{space}
   sleep,50
   sendinput,{MButton}
  }
 else
 {
 SendInput,!{Esc} 
 }
}
return
```

But unfortunately when I hold the button in the search bar of my dictionary it just type something like

> j  jjjjjj j jjj  j  jjjjjj j jj

Rather than doing the functions. I don't know how to fix the script.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by asking on autohotkey.com ([this post](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=89093&p=392609#p392609) ).

Here is the script by the user @mikeyww that solved my problem:

```
#IfWinActive Oxford Advanced Learner
$j::
KeyWait, j, T.2
If !ErrorLevel
{ Send j
  Return
}
If WinExist("ahk_exe KMPlayer64.exe")
{ WinActivate
  Send {Space}{Enter}
} Else Send !{Esc}
KeyWait, j
Return
#IfWinActive
```